# Is Coin a reserved word?

Tags: contract-development, contract-debugging, mix

If I try to compile the following example code in Mix it doesn't work. As soon as I change the name from Coin to Coins it starts working as supposed? Is this a bug or a feature?

```
contract Coin {
    // The keyword "public" makes those variables
    // readable from outside.
    address public minter;
    mapping (address => uint) public balances;

    // Events allow light clients to react on
    // changes efficiently.
    event Sent(address from, address to, uint amount);

    // This is the constructor whose code is
    // run only when the contract is created.
    function Coin() {
        minter = msg.sender;
    }
    function mint(address receiver, uint amount) {
        if (msg.sender != minter) return;
        balances[receiver] += amount;
    }
    function send(address receiver, uint amount) {
        if (balances[msg.sender] < amount) return;
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        balances[receiver] += amount;
        Sent(msg.sender, receiver, amount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Coin` contract is included in the [Solidity standard library](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Solidity-standard-library) – a feature from Proof of Concepts times. The standard library includes following contracts:

- `Config`,
- `Coin`,
- `CoinReg`,
- `coin`,
- `service`,
- `owned`,
- `mortal`,
- `NameReg`,
- `named`,
- `std`,
- `configUser`.

Currently all uses of them are discouraged except for `owned` and `mortal`.